# Knockout component w/ custom element not working similar as component binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using knockoutjs; I have a custom component that works when used as a component binding but fails when used as a custom element.

See fiddler here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmgbfthq/4/

Why is it working as expected when using component binding but not when using as a custom element? Shouldn't it work exactly the same way?

```
<!-- params.loads is coming in as a function -->
<metric params="value: loads()"></metric>

<!-- params.loads is coming in as a value -->
<div data-bind="component: {
        name: 'metric',
        params: {
                value: loads()                   
        }
    }"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you keep re-wrapping your value with `ko.observable()`,
while `params.value` *already is* an `observable`.

Try this instead:

```
viewModel: function(params) {
    this.value = params.value;
    this.format = params.format;
},
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmgbfthq/7/)

Comment: Makes sense, but this doesn't work with 'static' values <metric params="value: 100"></metric>

Comment: And even so, why are a custom element treated differently than a component binding?

Comment: See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#advanced-accessing-raw-parameters for explanation

Comment: As for 'static' values: You can't expect for it to work with non-observables because the component will never get notified when the value changes. Right now you're passing an observable from outside the component and doing the actual work using `setInterval` (again, outside of the component).